How to write asterisk without a space in between
I'm trying to write F*(v) (the asterisk in the middle) and works writing:
$F*$$(v)$

Because the natural way:
$F*(v)$

makes a separation in between the F and the asterisk, and between the asterisk and the first (.
Is there a way to write what I need without having to write it in the form $F*$$(v)$?

F{*}(v) maybe, but do you want F^{*}(v)?

isn't that an superscript? So $F^{*}(v)$?

$F{*}(v)$ worked! Thank you very much, I needed it without superscript, great :D

Glad it worked. Out of curiosity, what does F{*}(v) stand for?

Tangent map at a point $p$ :)

I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by a comment.
